# Текст в кавычках заменить прописным

Tags: c#

Как сделать, чтобы текст в кавычках заменить прописным?

```
static void Main()
    {
        string path = @"D:\GITHUB\C#\222.txt";
        string s = File.ReadAllText(path);
        bool toUp = false;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(var c in path)
        {
            if(c == '\"') { toUp = !toUp; continue; }
            sb.Append(toUp ? char.ToUpper(c) : c);
        }
        string appendText = s;
        File.WriteAllText(path, s);
    }
```

Comment: чем не устраивает `path.ToUpper()`?

Comment: если заменить на `path.ToUpper()` то начинает ругаться на ошибку

Comment: ну исправь её..

Comment: знал бы я как...

Comment: ну если бы ты не как блондинка из бухгалтерии сказал про асбтрактное "начинает ругаться на ошибку", а как здравомыслящий человек описал что за ошибка, на какой строке, показал как именно ты это делаешь - то было бы чем помочь. А так - неизвестно чего ты ожидаешь

Comment: Поменял `char.ToUpper()` на `path.ToUpper()`. Вот сама ошибка: "Не удается определить тип условного выражения, так как неявного преобразования между `string` и `char` не существует."

Comment: а зачем ты это употребляешь в тернарном операторе? зачем ты это вставляешь в цикл? Зачем тебе вообще в данном случае цикл?

Comment: только начал изучать C#, думал так будет работать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский может подскажите как делать, хотя бы псевдокодом

Comment: для ответа маловато, пусть тут пока полежит. После `var s = "AbCdEfGh".ToUpper()`, s будет содержать "ABCDEFGH"

Comment: Простите, а вы этот код сами писали? Вы понимаете, для чего вам `StringBuilder`? Вы записали в него текст, и что вы с ним делаете дальше?